# Accessing images from isolated storage in XAML using "isostore:/" scheme

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, isolatedstorage

I've downloaded images from the web and saved them to the Isolated Storage and now I want to access those images in my XAML file, giving a Uri as a reference to them.

I have verified with IsoStoreSpy that they are stored properly where I would expect them to be and I can create BitmapImages from them if I open the file and read in the byte stream. But now I want to optimize my image handling by passing just a Uri from my model to the IsolatedStorage location and letting my XAML load the image.

```
<Image Height="120" Width="120" Stretch="Uniform" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
   <Image.Source>
     <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding PodcastLogoUri}" DecodePixelHeight="120" DecodePixelWidth="120" /> 
   </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

This is the `PodcastLogoUri` Uri value that is bound to BitmapImage.UriSource:

> "isostore:/PodcastIcons/258393889fa6a0a0db7034c30a8d1c3322df55696137611554288265.jpg"

Here's how I've constructed it:

```
public Uri PodcastLogoUri
{
    get
    {

        Uri uri = new Uri(@"isostore:/" + PodcastLogoLocation);
        return uri;
    }
}
```

Still, I can't see an image in my UI. And I am sure the image is at `PodcastLogoLocation`.

Should it be possible to reference images to the UI from the isolated storage like this in Windows Phone 8? What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:** If I create the BitmapImage directly using the same path and use the BitmapImage in XAML, it works fine and I can see the image I expect to see there:

```
<Image Height="120" Source="{Binding PodcastLogo}"  Width="120" Stretch="Uniform" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
```

```
 public BitmapImage PodcastLogo
 {
     get
     {
          Stream stream = null;
          BitmapImage logo = new BitmapImage();
          using (var isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
          {
              if (isoStore.FileExists(PodcastLogoLocation))
              {
                 stream = isoStore.OpenFile(PodcastLogoLocation, System.IO.FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                 try
                 {
                      logo.SetSource(stream);
                 }
                 catch (Exception e)
                 {
                 }

            }
        }

        return logo;
     }
 }
```

Comment: It is, try without `UriKind.Absolute` ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it didn't help. :-(

Comment: Maybe my question isn't as straight forward as I've anticipated. I also posted it on MSDN forums, and I've gotten no answers to it. I really thought it's just me not grokking something and I would get someone pointing that out to me pretty quickly. Not so. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/0c1948a7-d4fc-4aa3-b30d-97213a7a816f/accessing-images-from-isolated-storage-in-xaml-using-isostore-scheme#0c1948a7-d4fc-4aa3-b30d-97213a7a816f

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I've done exactly the same thing that you're trying to do. What I've found is the absolute location where the Isolated Storage stores the file using `IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()`. This is something like `"C:/Data/Users/DefApps/AppData/<App Product ID>/Local/<YourFile.png>"`;

I've tested this workaround on Windows Phone 8 and it works for me...

**1. XAML**

```
<Image Width="40">
    <Image.Source>
        <BitmapImage DecodePixelWidth="40" DecodePixelHeight="40" UriSource="{Binding Path=Icon}" />
    </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

**2. ViewModel**

```
private string _icon;
public string Icon
{
    get
    {
        return _icon;
    }
    set
    {
        if (value != _icon)
        {
            _icon = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Icon");
        }
    }
}
```

**3. Load data**

```
filename = "Myicon.png";

IsolatedStorageFile store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
if (!store.FileExists(filename))
{
    using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(filename, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, store))
        stream.Write(imgBytes, 0, imgBytes.Length);
}

//get Product ID from manifest. Add using System.Linq; if you haven't already
Guid productId = new Guid((from manifest in System.Xml.Linq.XElement.Load("WMAppManifest.xml").Descendants("App") select manifest).SingleOrDefault().Attribute("ProductID").Value);
string storeFile = "C:/Data/Users/DefApps/AppData/" + productId.ToString("B") + "/Local/" + filename;

this.Items.Add(new MyViewModel() { Icon = storeFile });
```

Answer (score 2):

Sadly it seems this is not possible after all. I am a bit shocked and a lot disappointed by this. Can't really understand how MS doesn't support this case.

This is the answer I got over at MSDN forums:

> It Will Not Support XAML Binding Directly From Isolated Storage With
>   ISOStore URI Scheme.
>
> Here is Detailed Answer For Your Answer.
>
> http://mark.mymonster.nl/2013/05/24/yeah-windows-phone-supports-isolated-storage-access-through-an-uri-scheme-does-it

So that's it.