# Windows Phone: possible to convert IsolatedStorage path to "normal" absolute path in filesystem?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, isolatedstorage, isolatedstoragefile

I noticed that just about all audioplayers I can reach through code (XNA MediaPlayer and BackgroundAudioPlayer) need files at a special location - they just fail playing without any error message.

So I can copy the file to IsolatedStorage, now I need a normal path again (normal meaning one that fully qualifies it on the file system: an absolute path, so that I can use System.IO.File on it).

Is that possible, and if yes, how?

(I would like to give that path then to a Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media.MediaPlayer, hoping that it can play from that location, since it seems not to be able to play from arbitrary locations.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at [MediaElement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh465160.aspx)? (`System.Windows.Controls.MediaElement`) You can set the source of the control with an `IsolatedStorageFileStream`:

```
using (var isoStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
      if (isoStorage.FileExists(strFilename))
      {
          IsolatedStorageFileStream isoAudioFile = IsolatedStorageFileStream(strFilename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, isoStorage);

          medAudioPlayer.SetSource(isoAudioFile);                     
      }
}
```

Where medAudioPlayer is your MediaElement.

Note: this is for Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight apps. Not sure if it's available in Universal apps.

Comment: Thanks for example! Unfortunately, it does not work.. perhaps because I have the MediaElement not in xaml but rather in code? Also, I am targetting Windows Phone 8.0 SDK - don't know if there is a difference to 8.1 Silverlight.

Comment: Thanks for upvote! According to this link it is available for Windows Phone 8: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202883%28v=vs.105%29.aspx Which means you should be able to create it in code?

Comment: If you still need to get the absolute path, this may help: http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/how-find-out-where?mz=27249-windowsphone7 (From a discussion here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/d7659a65-3fda-4329-939e-29beed7153f9/how-do-i-get-the-full-path-of-a-file-in-isolated-storage?forum=wpdevelop)

Comment: Yeah, it should work. :)

Maybe I am missing something.. 

Also, I am not displaying the MediaElement, don't know if that makes a difference. (It is not in the XAML DOM.)

Getting absolute path from iso is working as per http://stackoverflow.com/a/24533312/586754 , also for non-changing GUID according to your link from dotnet.dzone. 

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you could try putting the MediaElement on the page but hide it? Bit of a hack, but if it works it works :)

Comment: Never made the MediaElement work, but also never touched the xaml. Since your comment above answers the question, I will mark the whole answer as.. the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you! Puts me back at the top of the office Stack Overflow Leaderboard hehe - cheers!